# Launch Celery without a virtualenv

Tags: python, celery, virtualenv

I'm trying to launch [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) installed with **pip** in a Docker container that doesn't use **virtualenv**.

`celery: command not found`

I tried to run

`python /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py`

but get `ImportError: No module named 'celery.five'; 'celery' is not a package`

When I do `pip freeze` I can see it's installed.

Running the command from a **virtualenv** works because `celery` is added to `<VENV>/bin/celery` and `<VENV>/bin/` is prepended to my `$PATH`.

How can I run [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) without using a **virtualenv**?

Comment: could you share which base docker image are you using?

Comment: The official python:3.4 image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside an installation using system's Python, the command `pip install celery` will usually install the binary under `/usr/local/bin`, so make sure that's in the `$PATH`.

Comment: This is what I thought at first but the binary is not there.. :/

Comment: Is there any environment variable or configuration I need to set to use that path as default for pip? Maybe it need to be done under a user different then root?

Comment: Are you using pip installed with `python3-pip` ubuntu package?

Comment: I just tried doing `docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:14.04`, then inside the docker container, I ran: `apt-get update && apt-get install python3-pip; pip3 install celery`, and then celery command worked out without issue.

Comment: I had a volume for /usr/local/lib/python3.4/ but not for /usr/local/bin, thanks a lot!